# Display Only One Category

Tags: categories

On my WordPress theme, it displays all of the categories a post is in on the homepage for the post block, I only want to display one category even if a post is under multiple categories.

i.e. Category One, Category Two, Category Three

I want it to be Category One...

This is the code that is in place at the moment:

```
<h2><?php the_category(', ') ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's snippet to display first category from post.

```
$category = get_the_category();

if ( $category[0] ) {
    echo '<h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</a></h2>';
}
```

Original idea of the code is from [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Show_the_First_Category_Name_Only)

Comment: When using this snippet of code, it doesn't simply any categories. It's simply blank.

Comment: Are using it inside the loop? Otherwise you need pass post ID into `get_the_category()`